# Функция в матлаб

Tags: matlab

функция stream3 в матлаб строит линии тока, есть способ узнать по какому алгоритму она работает

Comment: Почему вас волнует этот вопрос? Какой вы ожидаете увидеть ответ? Исходники матлаба вам никто не даст.

Comment: Почитайте статьи на тему "общее уравнение линии", и возможно часные случаи этого уравнения.

Comment: Я имею в виду что он с векторами скорости делает, мне сам код не нужен

Answer (score 1):

Вот исходный код этой функции: http://health.ahs.upei.ca/KubiosHRV/MCR/toolbox/matlab/specgraph/private/src/stream3c.c

Версия не самая последняя, но для понимания алгоритма работы будет достаточно

Comment: Спасибо огромное!)